# using Autofac with XML configuration

Tags: c#, xml, dependency-injection, autofac

I am trying to decouple an implementation where the interface is know and the implementation would be defined in App.Config. But it does not seem to be able to resolve the interface.

This is what I am doing :

```xml
<configuration>
  <autofac defaultAssembly="My.Service">    
    <components>
      <component type="My.Services.Service, My.Service" 
                 service="My.Abstractions.IService, My.Service" 
                 instance-scope="per-lifetime-scope" 
                 instance-ownership="lifetime-scope"
                 name="Service"
                 inject-properties="no"/>  
    </components>    
  </autofac>
</configuration>
```

And in my c# code

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new ConfigurationSettingsReader("autofac"));
var container = builder.Build();
IService service = container.Resolve<IService>()
```

When I run the code it is not able to resolve the IService, which is what I need. 
If I do the same but with the implementation in code instead of xml this is how it works.

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Service>().As<IService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
var container = builder.Build();
IService service = container.Resolve<IService>()
```

And here is the stacktrace

```
An exception occurred creating the service: IService ---> Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException: 
The requested service 'My.Abstractions.IService' has not been registered. 
To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service,
check for service registration using IsRegistered(), 
or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context,IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context)
```

Can anyone explain me how I can resolve the interface when using xml configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error come from the `name` attribute specified in your config file.

```xml
<component 
      type="My.Services.Service, My.Service" 
      service="My.Abstractions.IService, My.Service" 
      instance-scope="per-lifetime-scope" 
      instance-ownership="lifetime-scope"
      name="Service"
      inject-properties="no"/>
```

Is equivalent to :

```
builder.RegisterType<Service>()
       .Named<IService>("Service")
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

To have what you want, only remove the `name` attribute and you don't need to specify default value.

```xml
<component 
      type="My.Services.Service, My.Service" 
      service="My.Abstractions.IService, My.Service" 
      instance-scope="per-lifetime-scope" />
```